# Changing html table row values indexes with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenarion where I delete rows in a html table. Once the row is deleted, I am trying to realign/sort the hidden fields indexes. 
for example if second row with hidden fields `name[1]abc` tr is deleted, then I am trying to generate table with rows having hidden fields with index `name[0]` and `name[1]` etc., Any pointers ?

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bvw0gwd/)

```
<table class="links-list">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <input type="hidden" name="name[0]abc">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[0]def">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[0]gh1">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <input type="hidden" name="name[1]abc">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[1]def">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[1]gh1">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <input type="hidden" name="name[2]abc">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[2]def">
      <input type="hidden" name="name[2]gh1">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
//Loop through table rows
//get all hidden fields for each row
// update index value inside name[index] in sorted order
// like all hidden fields with name[0] in first row name[1] for second row etc
function updateHyperlinkIndexes() {
  var linksList = document.querySelector('.links-list tbody');
  for (var i = 1; i < linksList.children.length; i++) {
    var trContent = linksList.children[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < trContent.children.length; i++) {
      if (trContent.children.item(i).type && trContent.children.item(i).type === "hidden") {
        var cellName = trContent.children.item(i).name;
        trContent.children.item(i).name = cellName.replace(/[.*]/, i);
      }
    }
  }
  return linksList;
};

var updatedHtml = updateHyperlinkIndexes();
```

Comment: Does the code you have not work?

Comment: Your table's class in html is `linksList` but your selector looks for `links-list`. Also in `cellName.replace(/[.*]/, i)` you'd need to escape the brackets, and put back the brackets in replacement expression.

Comment: code did not work. any pointer?

Comment: This should not work at all. a `<tr>` will only accept either a `<td>` or `<th>`. The `<input>` needs to be in a `<td>` if you want it in the `<table>` whether it's hidden or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem, PFB working updateHyperlinkIndexes() function.

```
var linksList = document.querySelector('.links-list tbody');
  for (var i = 0; i < linksList.children.length; i++) {
    var trContent = linksList.children[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < trContent.children.length; j++) {
      console.log(trContent.children[j]);
        if (trContent.children.item(j).type && trContent.children.item(j).type === "hidden") {
        var cellName = trContent.children.item(j).name;
        trContent.children.item(j).name = cellName.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '['+i+']');
      }
    }
  }
```

Changes made include correction of replace regex expression, it should be `replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '['+i+']');`. And secondly you used same variable `i` for iterating nested loops.

Hope it helps you.